# Few fat models vs. many slim models in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

Any difference, performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too situation dependent to give a canonical answer.  With fat models PHP will be compiling a larger class to opt-code on each request cycle, much of which it doesn't need.  With many thin models PHP will need to instantiate more classes at run-time for your application to work.  Each could become a theoretical performance bottleneck under different situations (although your actual database connection will become a problem long before that).